# how to create a model / dto for data returned by MS Graph Delta user API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, microsoft-graph-api

**Background**

I'm trying to create a model / DTO class that represents the data we get back from calling
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta

There are some fields that are being returned that I don't know how to model.

**Current Code**

This class was auto generated for me when I copied a sample record returned to me by the API, and doing a Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes in Visual Studio.

```
 public class GraphUserDeltaApiDto
{
    public bool accountEnabled { get; set; }
    public string[] businessPhones { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDateTime { get; set; }
    public string department { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string employeeId { get; set; }
    public string givenName { get; set; }
    public string mailNickname { get; set; }
    public string onPremisesDistinguishedName { get; set; }
    public string officeLocation { get; set; }
    public string onPremisesDomainName { get; set; }
    public string onPremisesImmutableId { get; set; }
    public DateTime onPremisesLastSyncDateTime { get; set; }
    public string onPremisesSecurityIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string onPremisesSamAccountName { get; set; }
    public bool onPremisesSyncEnabled { get; set; }
    public DateTime refreshTokensValidFromDateTime { get; set; }
    public string securityIdentifier { get; set; }
    public DateTime signInSessionsValidFromDateTime { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public string userPrincipalName { get; set; }
    public string userType { get; set; }
    public string extension_2d3asdfasdfasdf777b68da_extensionAttribute1 {get; set;}
    public string extension_2d3asdfasdfasdf777b68da_extensionAttribute5 {get; set;}
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Onpremisesextensionattributes onPremisesExtensionAttributes { get; set; }
    public Passwordprofile passwordProfile { get; set; }
}

public class Onpremisesextensionattributes
{
    public string extensionAttribute1 { get; set; }
    public object extensionAttribute2 { get; set; }
    public object extensionAttribute3 { get; set; }
    public object extensionAttribute4 { get; set; }
    public string extensionAttribute5 { get; set; }
    public object extensionAttribute6 { get; set; }
    public object extensionAttribute7 { get; set; }
    public object extensionAttribute8 { get; set; }
    public object extensionAttribute9 { get; set; }
    public object extensionAttribute10 { get; set; }
    public object extensionAttribute11 { get; set; }
    public object extensionAttribute12 { get; set; }
    public object extensionAttribute13 { get; set; }
    public object extensionAttribute14 { get; set; }
    public object extensionAttribute15 { get; set; }
}

public class Passwordprofile
{
    public object password { get; set; }
    public bool forceChangePasswordNextSignIn { get; set; }
    public bool forceChangePasswordNextSignInWithMfa { get; set; }
}
```

The fields I'd like to ask about are:

```
    public string extension_2d3asdfasdfasdf777b68da_extensionAttribute1 {get; set;}
    public string extension_2d3asdfasdfasdf777b68da_extensionAttribute5 {get; set;}
```

It looks like these fields are just a repeat of the fields inside the Onpremisesextensionattributes class, except they have a unique ID baked into the fieldname.
Here's some sample data (just showing the relevant fields):

```
    extension_2d3asdfasdfasdf777b68da_extensionAttribute1= "ABC",
    extension_2d3asdfasdfasdf777b68da_extensionAttribute5= "Sync",
    extension_2d3asdfasdfasdf777b68da_employeeNumber = "asdfb-4234-1234-fa52-123fasf",
    id= "asdfasdf-asdf-asdf-asdf-asdf",
        onPremisesExtensionAttributes= {
            extensionAttribute1= "ABC",
            extensionAttribute2= null,
            extensionAttribute3= null,
            extensionAttribute4= null,
            extensionAttribute5= "Sync",
            extensionAttribute6= null,
            extensionAttribute7= null,
            extensionAttribute8= null,
            extensionAttribute9= null,
            extensionAttribute10= null,
            extensionAttribute11= null,
            extensionAttribute12= null,
            extensionAttribute13= null,
            extensionAttribute14= null,
            extensionAttribute15= null
        },
```

**Question**

I'm in the process of creating this DTO WITHOUT the extra fields, and seeing if I can populate a List to see what happens.
But why are these extra / duplicated fields coming back?  Is there any way I can change the result set to exclude them and only pass the data inside the Onpremisesextensionattributes class?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If you want to prevent these extra/repeated fields from coming back, you can add if judgment in get. Your corrections are welcome.

Comment: Here is the sample for creating the Data Transfer Objects (DTOs):https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to completely answer the question, but perhaps this info may help.

The extensionAttribute values in the Onpremisesextensionattributes class are a fixed set of legacy attributes that are generally used to manage properties that are shared between an on-premises and cloud sync for directory data.

Properties that follow the pattern of "extension__extensionAttribute" are not a fixed part of the Graph Schema, but represent custom schema created by the tenant owner to customize their Graph API functionality.  You can learn more about those here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview?tabs=http